# How to resize a NetCDF file so it matches the grid and coordinates of another NetCDFfile in R

Tags: r, arrays, netcdf, netcdf4

I have two .nc files, file1.nc and file2.nc The dimensions of the files are the following:

- file1 [lon,lat,t]=[21,9,t1] 0.25x0.25 Grid
- file2 [lon,lat,t]=[9,3,t2] 0.5X0.5 Grid

Each netcdf file have different time ranges but I'm only interested in the xy grid.
I want to transform file 1 so it has the grid size and same coordinates as of file 2. I have attached a picture so my explanation is clearer.
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOa29.jpg)

Some remarks:

- Some recommend using CDO (Climate Data Operators) but since I'm using my company's computer I don't have the permits to install what's required to run CDO.
- Other recommend to use `resample()` but they apply it to rasters which only visualizes one point in time and I want to resize the entire NetCDF.
  -I would like to perform the transformation either by using the netcdf file it self or the multivariate array resulting from extracting one variable form the netcdf file.

Comment: You do not need permissions to install CDO. Either install it locally, which isn't too difficult on Linux. Or install it through conda.

Comment: To use CDO I need to install cygwin and that needs permissions. Is there a way to do it in R?

Comment: hi Gina, actually under windows 10 you can now install linux directly, cygwin and wine servers/emulators are no longer required. Then you can install cdo easily in the terminal using apt install